# How to fix 'Required parameter $path follows optional parameter $handlers ' production error in laravel 8 for payment?

Tags: controller, stripe-payments, laravel-8, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

When I do payment using PayPal or stripe, not possible to do payment. I have implemented PayPal to purchase plans.

When I check it in logs it says

```
production.ERROR: Required parameter $path follows optional parameter $handlers {"userId":304,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Required parameter $path follows optional parameter $handlers at /home/hellovcard/public_html/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php:53)
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply means, the arguments (parameters) for a method in "PayPalRestCall.php" at line 53 is containing a required parameter after an optional one, something like :

```
function do_something($param_1 = 'hello', $param_2, $param_3 = 'world') 
{

}
```

The required parameters ($param_2) which don't have a default value must come first and then the optional ones with their default values.

To solve that, you should either move $param_2 to the first place so that it becomes the first parameter or give it a default value to make it optional too.

```
function do_something($param_2, $param_1 = 'hello', $param_3 = 'world') 
{
    
}
```

Or

```
function do_something($param_1 = 'hello', $param_2 = 'default_value', $param_3 = 'world') 
{
    
}
```

Comment: I've never understood the thought process behind whoever decided this was a good idea as a change in PHP. In my view, the second suggestion (setting `'default_value'` on `$param_2`) is really the only solution. Because if you start changing the _order_ of the parameters, anything that calls the function would need updating as well. It's a silly change and could lead to *more* errors. If you're having to fix this make very sure you check where the function (c.f. `do_something()`) is being called in your codebase before changing the order otherwise you could end up passing the wrong values!